# Composing dice throw probabilities

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose we are given a series of probabilities $p_a=0.2, p_b=0.1, p_c=0.5$ and $p_d=0.3$, for obtaining the value $4$ in a fair-dice throw. But the estimates were obtained for varying number of throws, e.g. the estimate of experiment $a$ was obtained after $5$ throws, so $n_a=5$, for others $n_b=10, n_c=3, n_d=6$.

- Question is, how should one correctly compose these probabilities, in order to give a final estimate $p$ from the gatherrd statistics? Should one be careful of the normalization used for the $p_i$'s?

My first attempt was to take a weighted average of them, using the ratio between individual throws and total throws as weight, i.e.:
$$n=\sum n_i$$
so
$$p=\frac{n_a}{n}p_a+\frac{n_b}{n}p_b+\frac{n_c}{n}p_c+\frac{n_d}{n}p_d$$

- Is this a valid way of going about composing the probabilities of different experiments?

Comment: I wouldn't describe it as "composing the probabilities" as it really just counts the $4's$ (whereas the probabilities would only retain average data).  That is...if $h_i$ denotes the number of $4's$ observed in $n_i$ throws then $p_i=\frac {h_i}{n_i}$ so your formula is just $p=\frac {\sum h_i}n$, a.k.a. "total number of $4's$ divided by the total number of throws".

Comment: Yes.  Well, assuming that the $p_a$ were computed in the way I said ($\frac {h_a}{n_a}$).  then your weighted average just recovers the $h_a$ and re-estimates the probability.

Comment: @lulu I see what you mean, great then :) I'm wondering, in general, say someone else does the same experiment elsewhere, but with a different total number of throws $n',$ comes to me and says my probability $p'$ was this, with $n'$ many throws. Are our estimates of p and p' directly comparable? even though we have different number of total throws? do we have to renormalize them or somehow take into account an error window?

Comment: Well, the two of you should be estimating the same thing so you'd hope the numbers were at least correlated.  Of course you'd have greater faith in the experimenter who looked at more throws (if you got a $6$ on your first throw you'd estimate $p=0$ but you really shouldn't have any confidence in that).  If you read up on Binomial Distributions you'll see standard error estimates for this sort of thing.

Comment: Yes...you are only worried about $4$ or not-$4$.  The Multinomial Distribution is a generalization you could use if you want all six probabilities.  I like [Grimmett & Stirzaker](http://www.amazon.com/Thousand-Exercises-Probability-Geoffrey-Grimmett/dp/0198572212/ref=sr_1_9?ie=UTF8&qid=1462534170&sr=8-9&keywords=probability+problems) but there are plenty of sources (starting online isn't a bad plan).

Comment: I agree with everything @lulu wrote in principle, but the estimates $p_c=0.5$ and $p_d=0.3$ cannot have been obtained from $n_c=3$ and $n_d=6$ throws in this manner, since they're not multiples of $\frac13$ and $\frac16$, respectively. Also I don't understand what you mean by "probabilities [...] for obtaining the value $4$ in a fair-dice throw" -- the probability for obtaining the value $4$ in the throw of a fair die is by definition $\frac16$, and it doesn't make sense to try to estimate it. The rest of the question sounds like you're estimating the probability for a certain unfair die.

Comment: @joriki you are right, the numbers were chosen randomly here, and it is a hypothetical scenario, with the intent of learning how one would go about estimating such probabilities, from scattered experiments, so this is really learn-by-example if you will. As you say we know that it is already $1/6.$ I appreciate your points though, specially since you looked so carefully at the numbers ;)

Comment: I'm not sure what that implies. When you say the numbers were chosen randomly, I suspect you mean arbitrarily? So are you saying you chose them incorrectly, not taking into account that they should be multiples of $\frac1{n_i}$? Or are you saying that they're not in fact meant to be multiples of $\frac1{n_i}$?

Comment: @joriki yes, meant to say arbitrarily.

Comment: But you didn't answer the more important second question. Now I still don't understand whether they were meant to be multiples of $\frac1{n_i}$ or not.

Comment: @joriki Sorry, no they weren't meant to be multiples of $1/n_i.$ I'm really sorry I didn't mean to cause such confusions, should have paid more care when writing the post :(

Comment: Then I don't understand why you seemed to agree with @lulu above. The discussion was based on the premise that these were estimates obtained by dividing the number of $4$s by the total number of throws in each case, and then your weighted calculation reconstructs the optimal estimate for the combined experiment. But if this is not how the estimates were obtained, we can't say much about how they should be combined. Do you know how they were obtained?

Comment: @joriki they were obtained as lulu said, and as you just said, namely dividing the number of $4$ occurrences by the number of throws $n_i$ in each case. Should not have used numerical values, instead wrote $p_a=x_a$ etc, to avoid the issues you mentioned previously.

Comment: @user929304: OK, I give up. If they were obtained in that way, they'd have to be multiples of $\frac1{n_i}$, that's why I asked, but you said that they're not.

Comment: @joriki I said they were chosen arbitrarily... as in could be multiples or not, irrelevant for the purpose of this question, they're just *some* numbers...

Comment: @user929304  Just to say:  there are other sensible ways of estimating the probabilities.  You could, for example, just start by assuming that $p=\frac 16$ then re-estimate using Bayes' Theorem as you get new data.  In that way, throwing a $4$ first wouldn't change your mind much, but starting out with five $4$'s in a row certainly would.  Doing it this way would make your "composing" problem a lot more delicate...as you'd need to keep track of the individual orders (and declare what you meant by the composite order).

Comment: @lulu Ah very interesting! By the way, you reckon I should remove the post at this point? since you basically gave me the confirmation I was looking for.

Comment: I'd leave it up, as the discussion might be interesting to others.  One thing you could do:  write up the discussion and post it as an answer below.  That's a nice way to close out the question.

Comment: @lulu done, hope it is okay the way I wrote things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As many interesting points have been already pointed out in the comments, and they in essence already contain the answer to the post, I decided to write them up here as an answer for future readers.

---

**Mainly extracted from [lulu](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/252071/lulu)'s comments:**

Since the individual probabilities in each experiment were obtained by dividing the total number of occurrences of value $4$ by the total number of throws of that experiment, the weighted average given for $p$ in the question, boils down to simply counting the overall occurrences of $4$'s from all experiments and dividing by the total number of throws $n.$ Thus one is not really composing probabilities, rather just doing the right counting.

Moreover as we were only interested in observing the value $4,$ we essentially treat all other values as failures, which means we can use the binomial distribution as model of choice. Otherwise the multinomial distribution can be used in a more general context.

Finally as to alternative ways of estimating the probabilities, lulu nicely points out:

> there are other sensible ways of estimating the probabilities. You
>   could, for example, just start by assuming that $p=1/6$ then
>   re-estimate using Bayes' Theorem as you get new data. In that way,
>   throwing a $4$ first wouldn't change your mind much, but starting out
>   with five $4$'s in a row certainly would. Doing it this way would make
>   your "composing" problem a lot more delicate...as you'd need to keep
>   track of the individual orders (and declare what you meant by the
>   composite order).

---

**Important points brought up by [joriki](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6622/joriki), as the post admittedly lacks in rigour:**

From the scheme given in the post for computing the probabilities $p_i,$ it follows logically that the probabilities should be multiples of $1/n_i,$ $n_i$ being the number of throws in experiment $i.$ But the chosen numerical values in the post do not seem to fulfill this condition, as a result of a blunder in arbitrarily choosing the values.

This point is of important relevance, as joriki points it out:

> The discussion was based on the premise that these were estimates
>   obtained by dividing the number of 4s by the total number of throws in
>   each case, and then your weighted calculation reconstructs the optimal
>   estimate for the combined experiment. But if this is not how the
>   estimates were obtained, we can't say much about how they should be
>   combined.

Comment: This looks very good (+1).